# Filesystem mounted as root but owned by user. Why?

Tags: mount, ownership

I'm mounting a filesystem as `root` and I don't understand why it is not owned by `root` but by an unprivileged user.

Here's fstab:

```
cat /etc/fstab
[...]
/dev/sdb        /mnt/projects ext4 defaults 0 2
```

And here's what happens when mounting:

```
ls -al /mnt/projects/ 
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 mai   25 17:55 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 mai   25 17:55 ..

mount /dev/sdb

ls -al /mnt/projects/ 
total 24
drwx------ 3 jerome jerome  4096 mai   25 17:52 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root   root    4096 mai   25 17:55 ..
drwx------ 2 root   root   16384 mai   25 17:52 lost+found
```

I'm not using `sudo`. I switch to `root` user with the `su` command.

The user that gains ownership is my normal user, the first declared when installing the system (uid: 1000).

The mount point is owned by root. I don't think that matters anyway.

My normal user doesn't have the permissions to mount the filesystem here himself.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This means that the file system being mounted contains a root directory owned by user 1000 and group 1000. The ownership of a mounted file system’s root directory becomes the ownership of the mount point.

Comment: I suppose this is because I created the partition using `gnome-disks` as unprivileged user. But there is nothing in that GUI informing me about it.

Comment: @Jérôme The owner of the root of a file system can be changed with `chown` just like any other directory.

Comment: OK @kasperd. I was just surprised it was `jerome` and not `root` in the first place since I thought I did everything as `root`.